# PHP: Collapse arrays of varying sizes into uniform nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an issue with an API I'm developing that returns arrays of lat/lon coordinates. In order to not break the parser on the App side, I need the data to return as uniform nested arrays, like this:

```
{
  coordinates: [
    [
      -88.451,
      41.41
    ],
    [
      -85.123,
      40.10
    ],
    [
      -59.451,
      42.42
    ],
    [
      -89.124,
      44.10
    ]
  ]
}
```

But for some reason the data I'm pulling from is occasionally nested into groups like this:

```
{
  coordinates: [
    [
      -88.451,
      41.41
    ],
    [
      -85.123,
      40.10
    ],
    [
       [
         -59.451,
         42.42
       ],
       [
         -89.124,
         44.10
       ]
     ],
  ]
}
```

If you have a good way to merge these nested arrays into a uniform set of nested arrays [[lat,lon],[lat,lon]] I'd be eternally grateful.

Much thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$myarray = [
    [
      -88.451,
      41.41
    ],
    [
      -85.123,
      40.10
    ],
    [
      -59.451,
      42.42
    ],
    [
      -89.124,
      44.10
    ]
];

function contains_array($array) {
    foreach ($array as $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
             return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function array_flatten($array, $return) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && contains_array($value)) {
            $return = array_flatten($value, $return);
        } else {
            $return[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

$res = array_flatten($myarray, array());
var_dump($res);
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Please note that the input is a JSON, not an array.

Comment: @Object Manipulator it is actually the short array syntax added in PHP 5.4

Comment: I'm well aware of the "short array syntax". If you look closely, you'll see the entire coordinates in the question is enclosed within curly braces { }